# Error: blackberry-nativepackager cannot be found on the path

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, cordova-3

I have develop phonegap application for IOS,Android,windows and now it's time to blackberry, but when time to set up phonegap blackberry i got err,i m using CLI cordovo command with use of node.js as i follow below instruction to create project but i at developing time i got below err.

Error: blackberry-nativepackager cannot be found on the path.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, do you maybe need to download a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Build Projectt :build project :navigate to project folder and cmd
  command : ant blackberry build
- Register with server : blackberry-signer -register -csjpin *123
  -cskpass @123 client-RDK-20***.csj
- sign app : blackberry-signer -storepass *@123 test.bar
- install app : blackberry-deploy -installApp -password @123 -device
  192... -package test.bar -password *@123 ((Navigate to sdk path bin folder under dependency ))
- Ref site :
  http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-code-signing-process/

Answer (score 2):

Have u downloaded the Blackberry SDK. You have install the blackberry sdk manually from blackberry's website. only then u can use it in phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and run the setup script from a BlackBerry 10 NDK. This is usually entitled something like bbndk-env.sh.